# Is there any fast and good way to create a dashboard for machine learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I am new to machine learning field, and I am trying to understand this code https://github.com/aninda052/Disasters-on-social-media-NLP/blob/master/Disasters%20on%20social%20media.ipynb, I think I am doing good at this, but my next step is trying to create a dashboard for this project to include all these results on it, my question is how to do this if it is possible? from where I should start? where I am supposed to put the model code? and اow much time will I need to finish this task? I am a bit confused so I would be grateful for any help, Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to ask a more narrow question, and just one question at a time. If, for example, there's a particular part of the code you have a question about, post that in your question and ask for an explanation. You are asking a lot of open ended questions, see the link above to learn how to ask better, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Dashboards are a great way to provide an interactive platform to display your work. There are 2 possible ways to create dashboards.

1. **Dashboard to build and train models** - Where you can change the parameters, plot training accuracy and loss etc. These are complicated and require a bit of software development. For python, you can try [Plotly dash](https://plot.ly/dash/), or [R Shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/) if you are using R.
2. **Dashboard to display results** - There are a number of softwares available to create dashboards from data in various formats. You can export your results to an `excel` of `csv` file and then generate interactive dashboards using [Tableau](https://www.tableau.com/) or Microsoft PowerBI ([sample dashboard](https://github.com/GDGVIT/DiseasePrediction))

Answer (score 0):

You can use superset which build on flask, flask app builder, python